# Oracle SQL query that deals with inner Joins and values

Tags: sql, oracle

```
    SELECT  sc.TAAC_SHARE_CLASS_ID,
    SCS.SHARE_CLASS_SID,
    SCS.REPORTING_DT,
    SCS.SHARE_CLASS_SNAPSHOT_SID, 
    SCS.DIST_UNMOD_30_DAY_YIELD_PCT, 
    SCS.DER_DIST_12_MO_YIELD_PCT, 
    SCS.DER_SEC_30_DAY_YIELD_PCT AS SCS_DER_SEC_30_DAY_YIELD_PCT, 
    SCS.DER_SEC_RESTATED_YIELD_PCT AS SCS_DER_SEC_RESTATED_YIELD_PCT
    FROM SHARE_CLASS sc 
    INNER JOIN PORTFOLIO P ON (P.PORTFOLIO_SID=SC.PORTFOLIO_SID)
    INNER JOIN SHARE_CLASS_SNAPSHOT SCS ON 
    (SCS.SHARE_CLASS_SID=sc.SHARE_CLASS_SID)
    WHERE SCS.REPORTING_DT = '24-JUL-17' AND P.PORTFOLIO_ID = 638;
```

I ran this query and got the following output : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9kBY.jpg)

Here, instead of getting separate rows for the same TAAC_SHARE_CLASS_ID, I want to merge the outputs of same TAAC_SHARE_CLASS_ID.

For example, the first row with TAAC_SHARE_CLASS_ID = 000648 should have values for all the 4 columns :

```
SCS.DIST_UNMOD_30_DAY_YIELD_PCT, 
SCS.DER_DIST_12_MO_YIELD_PCT, 
SCS.DER_SEC_30_DAY_YIELD_PCT,
SCS.DER_SEC_RESTATED_YIELD_PCT.
```

Hence the first row should have values for those columns as 2.96,3.2972596, 7541.085263433, 7550.

The last 4 rows of my output are not really required, as we have now merged those data into first 4 rows correspondingly.

How can I alter this query to achieve the same? Please help.

Comment: please click on image to see output of query

Comment: No thanks. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: why is this tagged MySQL your title says Oracle please fix the correct tag.

Comment: and what share_class_Snapshot-SID should be used or reporting_date etc...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you group your results by `TAAC_SHARE_CLASS_ID` column, and MAX() the remaining columns, something like this:

```
SELECT  sc.TAAC_SHARE_CLASS_ID,
        max(SCS.SHARE_CLASS_SID) as SHARE_CLASS_SID,
        max(SCS.REPORTING_DT) as REPORTING_DT,
        max(SCS.SHARE_CLASS_SNAPSHOT_SID) as SHARE_CLASS_SNAPSHOT_SID, 
        max(SCS.DIST_UNMOD_30_DAY_YIELD_PCT) as DIST_UNMOD_30_DAY_YIELD_PCT, 
        max(SCS.DER_DIST_12_MO_YIELD_PCT) as DER_DIST_12_MO_YIELD_PCT, 
        max(SCS.DER_SEC_30_DAY_YIELD_PCT) AS SCS_DER_SEC_30_DAY_YIELD_PCT, 
        max(SCS.DER_SEC_RESTATED_YIELD_PCT) AS SCS_DER_SEC_RESTATED_YIELD_PCT
FROM SHARE_CLASS sc 
INNER JOIN PORTFOLIO P ON (P.PORTFOLIO_SID=SC.PORTFOLIO_SID)
INNER JOIN SHARE_CLASS_SNAPSHOT SCS ON (SCS.SHARE_CLASS_SID=sc.SHARE_CLASS_SID)
WHERE SCS.REPORTING_DT = '24-JUL-17' AND P.PORTFOLIO_ID = 638
GROUP BY sc.TAAC_SHARE_CLASS_ID;
```

Comment: Group by throws an error. Says not a valid group by expression.

Comment: Did you just copy-pasted the solution or you added more columns to it? I can't see what could be wrong. You can try commenting all Max() lines, and re-enabling  them one by one to see which one is the line with the problem...